# ODBC Connection with integrated security PHP and MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, connection-string, integrated-security

I need the guidance help on ODBC connection string in PHP, which I am using to connect to MS SQL Server.

```
    <?php
$server = 'UKEMO03'; 
    $database = 'mtpFetch';//the database to connect to
    $user = 'shoabg';// the user has PERMISSIONS AT THE DATABASE
    $pass = 'Shsx12x';//and here the user's password
    $dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;";
    $connect = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pass); 
    ?>
```

Above code works treat, but i have a requirement of not to specify the username and password and use the connection string with Integrated Security. I can't find anything on internet and I can't change the connection string method because I've completed most of my work and by adapting another connection method will require a massive change in a code in theory its not an option for me.

Is there a way we can create Integrated Security connection to connect MS SQL Server in PHP using ODBC

Please help i don't know what to do

Comment: integrated security would mean php's connecting with the credentials of whatever account php and/or the webserver it's embedded in are running under.

Comment: I usually create in Dot Net 
server=1.1.1.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;

Answer (score 0):

This will connect you to the ODBC master database (cathalog).
I did not succeed to connect to another database. There is an option for default database in the configuration of ODBC SDN, but has no effect 
("Chenge the default database to").

```
$this->dbHandle = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI", '', '');
```

If you use PHP ini make sure you use:

```
mssql.secure_connection=On
```

On the database server, make sure you have Windows Authentification associated with your login username